# Using characters larger than 0xFFFF

Tags: unicode, itext

I have an OpenType font with some optional glyphs selected by features. I've opened it in FontForge and I can see that the associated unicode code point is, for example, 0x1002a.

Is it possible to use this value to render the glyph in iText? I've tried calling showText() with a string containing the corresponding surrogate pairs ("\uD800\uDC2A") but nothing appears.

Is there another way to do this, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Hi, this is definitely possible, but for now it's not even clear which version of iText you are using. Please show us your code